# Angular - Working with Computed Properties in the Models

Tags: angular, typescript

We are having developing an application where we have the below models:

```
interface IEmployee{
    firstName?: string;
    lastName?: string;
}

export class Employee implements IEmployee{
    public firstName?: string;
    public lastName?: string;

    constructor(data: object | Employee) {
        Object.assign(this, data);
    }

    get displayName(): string {
        return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
    }
}
```

We have another model - `Department` that refers the Employee class as below:

```
interface IDepartment{
    id?: string;
    name?: string;
    employees[]: Employee;
}
```

We are having two API calls at two instance of the project - one is for getting the users and the other for getting departments. While getting the employees, we are able to get the `displayName` of the Employee populated with the below code:

```
      this.http.get<Employee[]>(`${this.apiURL}\employees`)
      .pipe(map(response => {
        return response.map(data => new Employee(data));
      }));
```

Is there any way while getting the departments, to have the employee displaynames populated for all employees?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [combineLatest](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html), where you're able to define N observables for input like:

```js
combineLatest([departments$, employee$])
  .pipe(
     map(([departments, employee]) => /* do awesome staff */ )
  );
```

if both emit values, map will perform

Answer (score 0):

Well: your code is wrong. You should not write:

```js
this.http.get<Employee[]>(`${this.apiURL}\employees`)
```

The API does not return an Array of Employee, but Array of IEmployee.

You can write it like this:

```js
this.http.get<IEmployee[]>(`${this.apiURL}\employees`)
      .pipe(map(response => response.map(data => new Employee(data))));
```

That's the truth.

If you have an API which returns a list of Department and theirs employees, then you can write:

```js
    interface DepartmentInternal {
        id?: string;
        name?: string;
        employees: IEmployee[];
    }
    this.http.get<DepartmentInternal[]>(`${this.apiURL}\departments`)
      .pipe(map(response => response.map(dep => ({...dep, employees: dep.employees.map(e => new Employee(e))}))));
```

This should return your `IDepartment[]`.

After all, this is not a very good way to write typescript / javascript application. IMHO, `Employee` should not implement `IEmployee`, you do not respect Liskov Substitution by doing it.